# plyer notification in Python?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I made a water break in python it was working properly in the ide it was giving notification but when I used pyinstaller to make it into a .exe and when it should give notification it crashes so can anyone help me with this ?

```
from plyer import notification
import time
print("Welcome to Water Break")
Timer = int(input("What timer You would I like to keep?"))
print(" thank you will be reminded in",Timer,"mins")
time.sleep(Timer)
title = 'Water Break! '
message = 'it is time a for a WaterBreak'
notification.notify(title=title,
                    message=message,
                    app_icon= 'icon.ico',
                    timeout=10,
                        toast=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, because you need to specify explicitly hidden import

```
--hidden-import plyer.platforms.win.notification
```

see example here: https://github.com/beliaev-maksim/beta_build_downloader/blob/de0448ed1f9576791df51bae1e1805c0b8d53e60/electron_ui/compile_downloader_backend.cmd#L22

do not forget to upvote and mark as accepted answer if that help